# truffle not able to deploy internal used contract

Tags: migration, solidity, truffle

I'm using VS Code with Truffle Suite. I was able to deploy a HelloBlockchain contract from the truffle box to the ethereum goerli testnet.

Now I wanted to give it a try with duplicating an already existing contract to learn the usage of the truffle migration and how it deals when one contract is using an instance of another contract.

The contract I am trying to learn from is [this](https://arbiscan.io/address/0xb98058640970d8aa7bbce3b067b2d63c14143786#code) taken from the Arbitrum chain. This contract has defined another contract called DividendDistributor and its creating an instance of DividendDistributor within the constructor of itself. To not have any relation I rename it here to TokenCopy.

I was under the impression that a truffle migration would also deploy the code for the DividendDistributor however this doesn't seem to be the case.

The migration as below is failing with a "insufficent funds" error

```
const TokenCopy = artifacts.require("TokenCopy");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(TokenCopy);
};
```

I narrowed the issue down to the usage of the DividendDistributor in the constructor. When I remove that part truffle migration is deploying fine.

I changed the migration to the below, to first deploy DividendDistributor and then the TokenCopy contract

```
const DividendDistributor = artifacts.require("DividendDistributor");
const TokenCopy= artifacts.require("TokenCopy");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(DividendDistributor, "0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D"); // uniswap router on goerli testnet
  deployer.link(DividendDistributor, TokenCopy)
  deployer.deploy(TokenCopy);
};
```

This is working, its deploying both contracts (in two transactions)
[tx DividendDistributor](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xb1a21ffb13be61a7dfcf4af28acb6ece78674273d6372677a9469b7de5983bbf) and
[tx TokenCopy](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x284357080d45012dbbfcbf7c23018b1b82376c4a7d61705476021bc81a076ce7)

I would have thought that the deployment of the TokenCopy contract would use the DividendDistributor CA Address of my first deployment which is not the case. Instead I do see now two DividendDistributor deployments. One from my first deployer action and one done by the second deployer for TokenCopy. The contract creation is now also deploying an internal duplication of DividendDistributor.

The internal txns tab is showing this and I got two CAs for DividendDistributor.

I checked other questions here but none of it seem to deal with this exact situation where the other contract is only for internal use and no address need to be passed.

How can I avoid deploying DividendDistributor just to enable TokenCopy to deploy successfully with an internal deployment of DividendDistributor?